# HTML5 required input attribute lets me submit a form

Tags: jquery, html

I have a super simple form:

```
<form>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Your email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I'm submitting it using some jQuery (CoffeeScript style):

```
$('form').submit (event) ->
    do event.preventDefault()

    $.post('../mail.php', $('form').serialize(), (data) ->
        do $('form')[0].reset
    )
    .done -> ...
    .fail -> ...
    .always -> ...
```

In Chrome (as in Chrome Canary) it works like a charm, and it won't let me submit my form if some of the inputs are empty (it also displays the "Please fill out this field" message, as it should).
In a lot of other browsers though (Safari, WebKit Safari i.e.) it lets me submit the form with all the inputs empty.

What could the problem be? I'm a little worried about that `event.preventDefault`, maybe it stops some browsers from checking the `input`s?

Comment: could you post sample to jsfiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't rely on the support of `required` yet (unfortunately). See: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation
As you can see Safari is not yet fully supporting this API.

You shouldn't rely on this after all commonly used the browser implemented it either, as a malicous visitor might use a non-default browser and just skip these checks.

Comment: Not visiting caniuse has been really stupid and I apologize. I was so much into using Chrome that I assumed every other modern browser was supporting this. Sorry!

Comment: As a side note, Modernizr gives me a supported `require` input attribute even on browsers which don't fully support this property. Isn't that kind of bad for fallback solutions?